# Create a Windows executable (.exe) from Batch and Vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, executable

It is asked me to create a Windows executable (.exe) from scripts written in batch and vbscript. unluckily I don't know which tool use to realize that. Therefore Let me ask you some questions which torment my spirit

1. Is it possible to make a such build?
2. If it is, could you recommend me some open tools which do that?
3. To make an exe from bat+vbs, do you think I have to modify the
   content of my scripts alot/a little?

Thank in advance for your feedback

Comment: check bhx utility by carlos: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1642 .This will build bhx.exe with wich you can generate batch scripts that generate exes by passing an exe to them :)

Comment: and you have installed .net framework you can check it's compilers.

Comment: When you say "..build bhx.exe with which i can generate batch scripts that generate exes by passing an exe to them :), forgive me I don't really understand! In fact my scripts are written in batch+vbs and I'd like to build from them an exe.. I'm looking at carlos' site. But do you think it could help? Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Bat2Exe converts batch files including any other files in a certain folder into executables
http://www.bat2exe.net

Answer (score 0):

"ExeScript Editor" can convert batch files under **.bat** and **.cmd** also it can convert **.vbs** and **.vbscript** file into a ***.exe***

> http://www.scriptcode.com/vbscripteditor/

Comment: The software was asking to buy license during running while I'd like to test. Is there no evaluation of this tool? Thank for answering

Comment: i was involed in the development of the project, you can grab the single beta **.exe** File here : http://www.mediafire.com/?b59o545fsb2d35c

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

First : Join the bat files and vbs files together in one file.

Second: "Make" a executable of that file to launch the main bat file.

Bat/VBS file can't be compiled, when you see a "compiled bat" it's only a simple .exe stub, the bat is not compiled neither converted, is only stored, so first you need to use a joiner and second you need to use a bat-2-exe "converter" like "ExeScript Editor", searching for the crack in Google to evaluate the program is not hard, I have it.

...But really the best you can do is to use WinRAR application with the SFX options which can join files (compress), make the exe, and can launch the main bat file after silent extraction.

PS: Really the best you can do is to learn the basic things of a real lenguage, embbed the bat/vbs files as resources and then compile it into a standalone executable.