# how to open windows explore from Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, windows-7

When put file://myServer/network with file protocol in IE address line on windows 7, it will open Windows Explore to point to the network share folder.

but when I try it on Google Chrome, it won't open Windows Explore, all folder and file display with Chrome with browser mode.

How can I open Windows Explore in Chrome when put file://chorus.actra.ca/network in address line?

Comment: Chrome will not permit this behaviour due to security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Chrome will not open `file://` on the network for security reasons.

The only solution I know of for circumventing this entails adding a URL protocol key to the Windows registry hive `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` on the client's PC:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomfileopener]
@="URL:mycustomfileopener"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomfileopener\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomfileopener\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomfileopener\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\mycustomfileopener.exe %1"
```

You also need an executable (`mycustomfileopener.exe`) file that will pass the URL string (minus the `mycustomfileopener://` protocol portion) to the appropriate application available on the client's PC. This can be accomplished using some simple [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626500/1538708) it to `.exe`.

Now, when Chrome (or any browser) tries to open `mycustomfileopener://myServer/network`, it will automatically kickoff the aforementioned process, opening the URL directly on the network.